# Implement write lock for a database with zookeeper?

Tags: distributed-computing, apache-zookeeper, distributed-transactions

How would I use Zookeeper to enforce a single client write lock between a client and a database?

(i.e. only one client can write to the database at a time)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python doing this with Kazoo is trivial:

from kazoo.client import KazooClient

k = KazooClient(myhost)
k.start()

with k.Lock():
     do_exlusive_write()

Comment: Hey thanks! Docs are sparse for this stuff. What all would you store in Zookeeper? ACL's ,file metadata, database locations?

Comment: Bare in mind the default max size per znode is 1mb. Also, you want your workload in ZK to be read dominant so you don't want to store a lot of things that change tens of times per sec.